# How to use sum of values in SQL joins in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update a field in the database to the sum of its joined values:

I have this sample data:

```
ID  refer_id     my_reflink     s1  s2  m1  m2
-----------------------------------------------
1                      a                1   7
2      a               b                2   8
3      a               c                3   9
4                      d                4   0
5      b               e                5   1
6      c               f                6   2
```

I need a query that gives this result to s1 and s2.

```
ID  refer_id     my_reflink     s1   s2     m1  m2
----------------------------------------------------
1                      a         5   17     1   7
2      a               b         5   1      2   8
3      a               c         0   0      3   9
4                      d                    4   0
5      b               e         6   2      5   1
6      e               f         0   0      6   2
```

The result is

- s1 = sum of m1 for refer_id = my_reflink for each ID
- s2 = sum of m2 for refer_id = my_reflink for each ID

So for ID1, it will be

- s1 = 5 because ID 2 and ID 3 have `my_reflink` of ID 1 and m1 = 2 m1 = 3
- s2 = 17 because ID 2 and ID 3 have `my_reflink` of ID 1 and m2 = 8 m2 = 9

Comment: What database is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update/join syntax might be different depending on the RDBMS used but the below query works for MySql

```
UPDATE someTable t
JOIN (SELECT refer_id, SUM(m1) sum_m1, SUM(m2) sum_m2
      FROM someTable
      GROUP BY refer_id) s ON s.refer_id = t.my_reflink
 SET s1 = COALESCE(sum_m1, 0), s2 = COALESCE(sum_m2,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a `join`:

```
select t.ID, t.refer_id, t.my_reflink, tt.m1, tt.m2,
       t.m1, t.m2
from t left join
     (select refer_id, sum(m1) as m1, sum(m2) as m2
      from t
      group by refer_id
     ) tt
     on t.my_reflink = tt.refer_id;
```

If you want to actually change the data (rather than return a result set), then the `update` syntax depends on the database you are using.

Comment: i use msql 5.5.61  and i want to change data. Tnx